# Windows could not clean disk 0. Attempting to reimage a new laptop

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, unattended

All,

I have a laptop that I am trying to install an image over.  I have had success other laptops using this same USB drive; however, I am facing an error message I can't resolve on this particular device.

**The error:  Windows Could not clean disk 0. The specified disk does not exist.  The error occurred while applying the unattend answer file's  Setting.  error code: 0x80300025**

My thoughts are it is because this device does not support legacy boot.

The USB was created prior to my onboarding but I really like the functionality of it so I'd like to use it if possible.

Comment: "My thoughts are it is because this device does not support legacy boot." - While I strongly suggest NOT using legacy boot, the simplest solution to the problem, is to use the Media Creation Tool and recreate the media.  This will eliminate this possibility allowing you to [edit] your question and provide the necessary information to answer your question.  Be sure you delete any partitions that already exist on the drive.

Comment: Ramhound...thank you for your quick response.  So I am familiar with the Media Creation Tool; however, I would like to create an unattended image stick to create so I can start the process and go attend to other matters.

The stick was for that purpose but then we received new laptops that did not have the Legacy boot option and now we are unable to image the computers in that same fashion.

Comment: At the very least, test the new installation disk, to verify the problem is indeed your existing media